# issue when trying to delete one object from an array field (parse - ios)

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery, pfuser

I have a button where user can delete a friend:

it looks like this:

(`"self.otherUser"` is a `PFUser` instance which contains the friend user to delete)

(`"friends"` is an `array field` in the User table which contains friends `ObjectIds`)

```
PFQuery *deleteFriendQuery = [PFUser query]

[deleteFriendQuery whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[deleteFriendQuery whereKey:@"friends" equalTo:[self.otherUser objectId]];

[deleteFriendQuery getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

            [object delete];
        }];
```

Nothing is deleted in the data browser, where am I wrong ? Does anyone knows a way to do this ?

Comment: Excuse me, I believed that the "parse.com" tag suffices

Comment: I somehow missed that. Sorry. Adding it to the subject is still a good idea since it draws people who know the particular framework you're working with (I've used a little Firebase but not Parse.)

Comment: Parse offers very good backend services, but for me the documentation miss of precisions for some cases

Answer (score 0):

You are querying for a User object. User A does not have permission to delete User B.

Comment: do you have an idea ?

Comment: Yes I know, the current code deletes a user, but what I'm trying to do is to remove the friend to delete's objectId from the array field called "friends" in my User table

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
 [object delete]
```

for

```
 [object deleteInBackground];
  [object saveInBackground];
```